# Filtering a List Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I just started learning Haskell about filtering lists.
Suppose I have the following list : `[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11]`
I would like to keep only those numbers in the list, which are not divisible by the other members.

The result of our example would be : `[2, 3, 5, 11]`

Comment: What do you mean with minimum multiples

Comment: And? What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @VincentBeltman I gave more details in the example, thanks

Comment: You're not asking for a filter, you're asking for a reduction. `foldl1 gcd xs` gives your results. It can't be a filter, because the result of `min(2,3)` is 1, and 1 isn't in `[2,3]`

Comment: min(2,3) means the minimum between 2 and 3

Comment: Ok, just to re-phrase: you want to keep only those numbers in the list, which are not divisible by the other members. Right?

Comment: @bereal yes exactly, I'll re-phrase my question, yourse is more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[x | x <- src, all (\y -> x `rem` y /= 0) (filter (<x) src)]
where src = [2,3,4,5,8,10,11]
```

It should be noted that you actually also mean dividable by other numbers that are below it, and not just any number in that list, which is why there's a `filter` in the 2nd argument for `all`.

The result, of course, is the one you expect in your question: `[2,3,5,11]`.

---

Here's how it works (and if I'm missing anything, let me know and I'll update).

I'll explain the code side-by-side with normal English. I suggest you just read just the English first, and afterwards see how each statement is expressed in code - I think it should be the most friendly for a newcomer.
Also note that I flipped the arguments for `filter` and `all` below (it is invalid!) to make the explanation fluid.

`[x|`: Construct a list made out of `x` 
`x <- src`: Where `x` is an element from `src`
`,`: But only the elements that satisfy the following predicate/rule:
`all` of the numbers from
`(filter src (<x))`: `src` that are lesser-than the current `x`
`(\y -> x 'rem' y /= 0)`: must not yield a remainder equal to 0.
`]`

For the code part to make sense, make sure you've familiarized yourself with [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:all), [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter), [`rem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:rem), and the syntax for: [list comprehensions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension), [lambda expressions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#lambdas), [sections](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions), and [backticks](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#ready-set-go).

Comment: Thank you @MasterMastic, it's great your solution works, could you please explain to me? as I told you I am a beginner

Comment: @riad Certainly, will update in a few minutes and keep you posted.

Comment: @riad Check it now, and let me know if you'd like me to expand on anything.

Comment: On GHC, `nubBy (\a b->rem a b ==0)` does the trick. On Haskell98-compatible systems (e.g. Hugs), use `nubBy (\b a->rem a b ==0)`. (`nubBy` is in `Data.List`).

Answer (score 3):

On GHC,

```
Prelude> :m + Data.List
Prelude Data.List> nubBy (\a b -> rem a b == 0) [2,3,4,5,8,10,11]
[2,3,5,11]
```

does the trick. On Haskell98-compatible systems (e.g. Hugs), use `nubBy (\b a -> rem a b == 0)`.

*This answer was [posted as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161477/filtering-a-list-haskell/26173420#comment41020264_26163004) by [Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness).*

Comment: Technically this only works when the original list is sorted.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, Good Point! One way to fix it is rewriting of lambda so it always passes its arguments to `rem` in desired order (`rem max min`). But in this case the solution is not so sexy...

Answer (score 2):

Using `filter`

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

and from `Data.Numbers.Primes` the function

```
isPrime :: Integral int => int -> Bool
```

may be

```
filter isPrime [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11]
```

or using list comprehension

```
[ x | x <- [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11], isPrime x]
```

change filter predicate as you wish, e.g.

```
-- None `xs` element (different than `x`) divide `x`
noneDiv xs x = and [x `mod` y /= 0 | y <- xs, x /= y]
```

now

```
myFilter xs = filter (noneDiv xs) xs
```

or

```
myFilter xs = [x | x <- xs, noneDiv xs x]
```

Comment: it's not about prime numbers, for instance if I have 8, and 16 in the list, I keep 8 and eliminate 16